# Unable to make a new object by splitting the strings in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this array of strings which I need to split at "-" and make a new object with the split values. The strings can have multiple "-" but I want to split always at the last "-".

The array looks like this:

```
[
  'This is movie number 1. – Robert Downey Jr',
  'This is movie number 2. – Ben Afleck',
  'This is movie number 3. – Chris Evans',
  'This is movie number 4. – Robin Williams',
  'This - is movie - number 5. – Al Pacino',
  'This is movie number 6. – Dwayne Johnson',
  'This is - movie number 7. – Paul Rudd'
]
```

What I wish to achieve is this:

```
[
   {
      movie: "This is movie number 1.",
      actor: "Robert Downey Jr"
   },
   {
      movie: "This is movie number 2.",
      actor: "Ben Afleck"
   },
   {
      movie: "This is movie number 3.",
      actor: "Chris Evans"
   },
   {
      movie: "This is movie number 4.",
      actor: "Robin Williams"
   },
   {
      movie: "This - is movie - number 5.",
      actor: "Al Pacino"
   },
   {
      movie: "This is movie number 6.",
      actor: "Dwayne Johnson"
   },
   {
      movie: "This is - movie number 7.",
      actor: "Paul Rudd"
   }
]
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```js
const arr = [
  'This is movie number 1. – Robert Downey Jr',
  'This is movie number 2. – Ben Afleck',
  'This is movie number 3. – Chris Evans',
  'This is movie number 4. – Robin Williams',
  'This - is movie - number 5. – Al Pacino',
  'This is movie number 6. – Dwayne Johnson',
  'This is - movie number 7. – Paul Rudd'
];


const newArr = arr.map((el) => {
  const movie = el.split('-').shift();
  const actor = el.split('-').pop();

  return {
    movie: movie,
    actor: actor
  }
});

console.log(newArr)
```

I could make objects but both movie and actor holds the full string and not the split versions.

It would be highly appreciated if someone could help me with this.

Comment: try with stringValue.lastIndexOf('-')

Comment: Your last hyphen is `–` which is a different character from the other hyphens earlier on in your string `-`. Splitting by `–` instead of `-` should work if this is always the case

Comment: Can I use both the variations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lastindexof and substring to get what you want. Only problem could arise if actor name also has "-" in it. But rest works good

```js
const arr = [
  'This is movie number 1. – Robert Downey Jr',
  'This is movie number 2. – Ben Afleck',
  'This is movie number 3. – Chris Evans',
  'This is movie number 4. – Robin Williams',
  'This - is movie - number 5. – Al Pacino',
  'This is movie number 6. – Dwayne Johnson',
  'This is - movie number 7. – Paul Rudd'
];


const newArr = arr.map((el) => {
    const idx =   el.lastIndexOf("–");
   
  const movie = el.substring(0, idx);
  const actor = el.substring(idx+1);

  return {
    movie: movie,
    actor: actor
  }
});

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't working because the strings in sample data and your code is using different types of `-` :   -  vs –

```js
const arr = [
  'This is movie number 1. – Robert Downey Jr',
  'This is movie number 2. – Ben Afleck',
  'This is movie number 3. – Chris Evans',
  'This is movie number 4. – Robin Williams',
  'This - is movie - number 5. – Al Pacino',
  'This is movie number 6. – Dwayne Johnson',
  'This is - movie number 7. – Paul Rudd'
];


const newArr = arr.map((el) => {
  const movie = el.split('–').shift();
  const actor = el.split('–').pop();
  return {
    movie: movie,
    actor: actor
  }
});

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a reducer ([`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)) and [`String.lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) to determine substrings

```js
const arr = [
  'This is movie number 1. – Robert Downey Jr',
  'This is movie number 2. – Ben Afleck',
  'This is movie number 3. – Chris Evans',
  'This is movie number 4. – Robin Williams',
  'This - is movie - number 5. – Al Pacino',
  'This is movie number 6. – Dwayne Johnson',
  'This is - movie number 7. – Paul Rudd'
];
const arrAsObj = arr.reduce( (acc, val) => [
      ...acc, 
      { movie: val.slice(0, val.lastIndexOf(" – ")), 
        actor: val.slice(val.lastIndexOf(" – ") + 3).trim() } ], [] );
  
console.log(arrAsObj);
```